# Free Mac/Windows program for beginner to make dub-step bass/drum electronic music

Tags: windows, osx, music, music-composing

I am looking for a program for creating simple music, for mac/windows, preferably free.

My goal is to compose dub-step - bass/drum - electronic music. I have zero experience with such tools and it would be good if recommended tool would be for complete beginners.

Comment: Please exactly what you features you need. Thanks!

Comment: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software

Comment: @NicolasRaoul i have edited my answer

Comment: Have you had a play with Fruity Loops (yes, that's really its name)?

Comment: @spikey_richie i will give it a try, thanks